# Sign-in Failed with "Network Error" log

Tags: unity-game-engine, authentication, google-fabric

I'm using Unity for my project and trying to use Fabric sdk. I just downloaded 'Fabric.unitypackage' and import it to my project. After that, I tried to sign in with Fabric Editor in Unity. However, it failed over an over again. I have no idea why it's not working. 
There's error log with screen shot below. Anyone can help me?

```
{
"error": "invalid_resource_owner",
"error_description": "The provided resource owner credentials are not valid, or resource owner cannot be found",
"status": "unauthorized"
}
```

[Error Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMzYZ.png)

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. It's a bug on our end and we're working on a fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. Unfortunately, we made a mistake when we re-issued a certificate for our fabric.io domains on Sept 26 which requires that you re-download and import the Unity plugin into your project. Sorry for this, but once you download version 1.2.8 or higher from https://fabric.io/downloads/unity, you'll be all set.